# Generate an MDF finite element mesh containing LINK1 elements

Tags: awk

I got the following homework on the university:

> Write an AWK program, that can generate an MDF finite element mesh
>   containing LINK1 elements. The geometry of the mesh contains n pieces
>   of vertical lines and m pieces of horizontal lines. n and m values are
>   parameters for the AWK program. The vertical and horizontal distance
>   between the lines are also parameters. The shape of the mesh can be
>   seen in the following figure:

[the shape of the mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Mkh.png)

An example execution:

```
awk –v n=3 –v m=2 –v dn=2 –v dm=1 –f gen.awk > output.mdf
```

> Inputs:

`n` is the number of vertical lines

`m` is the number of horizontal lines

`dn` is the number of characters between the vertical lines

`dm` is the number of characters between the horizontal lines

> Output:

the `output.mdf` is the Measurement Data Format file i need to draw these lines in.

Like in this:

```
__|__|__|__
__|__|__|__
  |  |  |
```

And also:

> Please make sure the output.mdf file is valid. It is possible to use
>   the chkmdf.exe or e_plot32.exe program to check the validity of an MDF
>   file.

**Don't get me wrong I don't want someone to solve it for me, I know this platform is not for that. I only ask for some starter tips, documents**

Comment: We are willing to help you out, but we would need to know what the MDF format actually is. Can you point us to example or better even, a standard, which describes MDF? Also, I noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61203259) which looks remarkable similar.

Comment: Is this an `awk`/`*nixTools` class, or something where MDF is part of the target knowledge transfer? Good luck.

Comment: This seems to be a project designed so that you really understand printf format strings (and passing variable values to the format specifiers). So check out https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#toc-uh-29, then whip up some code, add it to your Q and you're likely to get some help. Good luck.

Comment: This site is intended to solve specific problems and is not intended for general how-to's. Please refer to the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said you just wanted tips and hints but life's too short to provide an awk tutorial here so here's how to do it if you were using `-` instead of `_` as the row separator character with no explanation:

```
$ cat gen.awk
BEGIN {
    numCols = n + 1
    colWidth = dn
    numRows = m + 1
    rowHeight = dm

    colSep = "|"
    rowSep = sprintf("%*s",colWidth,"")
    gsub(/ /,"-",rowSep)

    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (subRowNr=1; subRowNr<=rowHeight; subRowNr++) {
            for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
                printf "%*s%s", colWidth, "", (colNr<numCols ? colSep : ORS)
            }
        }
        if ( rowNr < numRows ) {
            for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
                printf "%s%s", rowSep, (colNr<numCols ? colSep : ORS)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -v n=3 -v m=2 -v dn=2 -v dm=1 -f gen.awk
  |  |  |
--|--|--|--
  |  |  |
--|--|--|--
  |  |  |
```

.

```
$ awk -v n=5 -v m=4 -v dn=6 -v dm=3 -f gen.awk
      |      |      |      |      |
      |      |      |      |      |
      |      |      |      |      |
------|------|------|------|------|------
      |      |      |      |      |
      |      |      |      |      |
      |      |      |      |      |
------|------|------|------|------|------
      |      |      |      |      |
      |      |      |      |      |
      |      |      |      |      |
------|------|------|------|------|------
      |      |      |      |      |
      |      |      |      |      |
      |      |      |      |      |
------|------|------|------|------|------
      |      |      |      |      |
      |      |      |      |      |
      |      |      |      |      |
```

and you can google the constructs, add `print`s, etc. to figure out what it's doing and so learn from that and fix it to output the exact format you want. I also highly recommend you get the book Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins - all other books about awk are incomplete and/or out of date and/or have other issues.

Comment: Wow that would take ages to figure out all by myself. Thank you for solving my problem and all the help during the question editing. I learnd a lot today, thank you.

Comment: Just one comment, `-|-`, could be replaced with `-+-` ;-)

Comment: @kvantour Yeah but that'd be adding just slightly more complexity and diverging even further from the OPs desired output.